# Flutter flutter_blue label printer issue

Tags: flutter, printing, label

I am new in flutter.
I am building an app to print on the ble label printer via Bluetooth.
I use flutter_blue library. I had successfully connected to the device and found the target characteristic. My problem is that when I call write() function of the characteristic printer show on display “waiting for data” and nothing is printed.
Could you please help me with the data format I need to put into the method?
I use utf8 encoded string as data.

```
    Future<void> _print() async {
      var serviceUuid = '0000ff00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';
      var characteristicsUuid = '0000ff02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb';

      _services.forEach((service) {
        if(service.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == serviceUuid) {
          printService = service;

          for (var c in printService!.characteristics) {
            if(c.uuid.toString().toLowerCase() == characteristicsUuid) {
              var ZPL_TEST_LABEL = 'Hello WeChat!\r\n';

              printCharacteristic = c;
              writeData(printCharacteristic, ZPL_TEST_LABEL);
            }
        }
      }});
    }
```

```
    Future<void> writeData(characteristic, data) async{
      if (characteristic == null) return;
      try {
        var utf8Encoded = utf8.encode(data);
        debugPrint(data.toString());
       var result = await characteristic.write(utf8Encoded);
        debugPrint(result.toString());
      } catch (e) {
        debugPrint(e.toString());
      }
    }
```

My first step is to print at least a string, could you pls help me?